# Url.Content() equivalent in php?

Tags: php, relative-path

What is the Url.Content() of asp.net mvc equivalent in php?

I have a file that use my style.css from both pathes:

1. 'artciles/123/name'
2. 'artciles/123'

How can I use links to static content, witout using absolute urls?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what Url.Content() do, but it sounds as you are after the [$_SERVER](http://php.net/$_SERVER) array, which contains information about the request, such as the host and URI given.
Check out `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.